# How to display and widget in all themes?

Tags: wordpress, widget

I have just created my first wordpress widget(which basically shows a name and address) and was able to display it correctly. But what I notice that if I change my theme then my created widget disappears from available widget area in admin panel; though there are many widgets which are always showed regardless of choosed theme(Like text widget). I want to know how can I make my widget available across all themes. Thanks.

Comment: those are core widget which comes with wordpress package

Comment: @wordpresser But what about page builder widgets? They are available in all themes after installing

Answer (score 1):

Make a [plugin](http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin) and inside it create your [widget](http://codex.wordpress.org/Widgets_API), now change your theme any number of times the widget will be still there .

Answer (score 0):

You have to add them individually for each special theme. Unless you use one theme and Apply that Widget to Main Position.

Comment: OK, then how come the text widget is available in all themes? Plus there are some 3rd party widgets, like the page builder widgets, which also available in all installed themes.

Comment: Cause you have a option to add them (widgets) to your sidebars (Which every theme you using have different type of sidebars and variety of them). Widgets get install separately then how many sidebar your theme support you can add them to it.